# SendBird: Want to implement Direct Messaging Feature, Only 1-1 chat

Tags: chat, integration, chatbot, sendbird

I am implementing chat in a application where I am integrating sendbird SDK. UI is working fine, Now the issue is sendbird has by default OpenChannel and GroupChannel messaging types.
GroupChannel is giving the option to do both 1-1 chat and group chat.
But I just want to impelement simple 1-1 chat between two users like direct messaging in normal applications.
It means user just search the do private 1-1 chat. User should not have the option of creating group in any way.
I'm tired to searching for this solution, Read Complete docs but comes up with no solution

Anyone can please help?

I have read all the docs and explore all Youtube tutorials but did not find any solution